# Calling PreferenceFragment method in API 8

Tags: java, android, material-design

I am an Android newbie trying to apply material design to an app I have. In the old app I called my settings menu entry loaded an activity that extended PreferenceActivity.

To modernise this I am trying to use PreferenceFragment as shown in the tutorial http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture12/lecture12.html

For API 8, the compiler won't allow me to call getFragmentManager(), only getSupportFragmentManager(). But the compiler won't allow me to load the new Fragment. My code is as shown below:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
MainSettingsFragment mPrefsFragment = new MainSettingsFragment();
mFragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mPrefsFragment);
```

I get a red line below mPrefsFragment and I get the following error message:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'com.src.xxx.MainActivity.MainSettingsFragment', required: 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment'
replace(int,android.support.v4.app.Fragment) in FragmentTransaction cannot be applied
to (int,com.src.xxx.MainActivity.MainSettingsFragment)
```

What am I doing wrong? To the best of my knowledge, the 2nd argument in replace, is of correct type.

Relevant sections of my code are shown below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item_edit_settings:
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                MainSettingsFragment mPrefsFragment = new MainSettingsFragment();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, mPrefsFragment);
                mFragmentTransaction.commit();
                //startActivity(new Intent(this, EditSettingsActivity.class));
                //new MainSettingsFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this));
                return true;            
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static class MainSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think the MainSettingsFragment is from the 'normal' package, and a Fragment from the supportJar is needed... This is not a solution, but the problem

Comment: @Danielson: Thanks. Is there any way to launch a fragment from the menu event? Launching the activity from the intent gets rid of the material design Toolbar

Comment: I dare not say. But is there not an SupportJar Activity to complement the supportFragment?

Comment: @Danielson: I haven't found one so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply use `PreferenceFragment` in API8, because it was added in API11. It can only be launched through `getFragmentManager()`.

If you really want to support older APIs, it might be better to stick with a `PreferenceActivity` with inner `Fragment`s in it. To stay on with the design, you can try the `AppCompatPreferenceActivity`.

It can be found both [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support7Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv7/app/AppCompatPreferenceActivity.java) and in the samples you can import through Android Studio (I think). It keeps the Preference functionality, but implements `AppCompatActivity` methods too.